# How to calculate the mean for a moving window (back and forth) and stander deviation for the window in R?

Tags: r, moving-average

I have  365 values from x[1] to x[365]. For each value I have to consider a windoe(x-17,x+17),so will start   from x[18]. I want to perform the calculations like this:

```
   x=1:365
 first period = (x[18]-17 vaues,x[18]+17 values)
```

example of my values(only one column exist in my file which is  values):

```
            values
     1      0.2
     2      0.3
     .      .
     365    0.4
```

Comment: Are these actually stored as separate variables named x1, x2, ..., x365?  Or are these rows/columns in a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a rolling mean using the `rollmean` function the zoo package.

```
# make some fake data
mydat <- 1:365
library(zoo)
mymeans <- rollmean(mydat, k = 35)
```

To get the rolling standard deviation you could use `rollapply` and supply it `sd` as the function to apply

```
mysds <- rollapply(mydat, 35, FUN = sd)
```

From there you could use the output to do the transformation of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for :

```
      library(zoo)
      rollapply(zoo(rnorm(x18)), 34, function(x)mean(x)/sd(x))
```

Comment: @Barry what??!! x18 refers to what in your question so ?? that's said change x18 to 1:365.